# insert caret in a new node for IE (DHTML)

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable, dhtml

In a contenteditable div, if I click on a button, I want to add a new FONT node and to put the caret in it.

I don't manage to do it.

```
Rng = document.selection.createRange();
var node =  document.createElement("font");
node.setAttribute("size", "8");
Rng.pasteHTML(node.outerHTML);
Rng.collapse(true);
Rng.select();
```

I try a lot of things, with moveStart, setStartAfter,...

I need your help.

For the moment, I get the caret just after the . I want it before.

I need to develop it for IE >9.

Comment: DHTML is dead and buried for a long time ago. If you're targetting IE>9, you need to get familiar with the modern [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) models.

Comment: Wow. I don't remember the last time I saw a `font` element in real-world usage.

Comment: I need to use FONT because in a contenteditable div, IE uses FONT